# flexbox with a table child

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox based layout that I want to look like this:

```
 _______________
| top banner    |
|---------------|
| tabular data  |
|               |
|_______________|
```

With the tabular data taking up whatever size is available after the banner.

This works if `B` is `display: block`, but not if it's `display: table` (see http://jsfiddle.net/E4Qbw/).

```
.container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
     -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    border: 1px dashed #fc0;
}

.A {
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.B {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="A">
           A
    </div>
    <table class="B">   
        <thead>
            <tr><th>B</th></tr>
        </thead>     
    </table>
</div>
```

I've also experimented with wrapping the table inside a `block` container to no avail.

Is there any way to accomplish this with my current table?  Or do I need to use some other structure?

Comment: The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-items) has some info on flex items that are displayed as tables.

Comment: This sounds like a bug report for the Webkit team since it is a spec violation, not an SO question.

Comment: @cimmanon if it's a spec violation please provide that (along with your reasoning) as an answer.  Otherwise the question is pretty clearly how to accomplish the layout described in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do it by wrapping `table` into a `div` wrapper with the `flex: 1` property. Then I set `height: 100%` for a table. In this case the `tbody` tag is required.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="A">
       A
  </div>
  <div class="B-wrapper">
    <table class="B">   
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Header</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Row</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

The styles:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    border: 1px dashed #fc0;
}

.A {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.B-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.B {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ischenkodv/E4Qbw/58/

Answer (score 3):

This problem puzzled me for a while too: "How do you make things behave rationally again inside Flexbox?".

My solution is to use

```
"position: absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;"
```

Here is my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E4Qbw/10/. May be that helps.

I also think this is a major problem with Flexboxes. May someone with deeper expertise can help us out here.

BTW: I could not get this to work using THEAD, so the Fiddle now has a TBODY instead.

Comment: Would love to have a better understanding of *why* this is working, and why tables are special inside flexboxes where they don't work on their own or follow normal sizing.